# What is the replacement for Base64.getEncoder().encode() in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aes, rsa

I am using this code.

```
fun rsaEncrypt(rsaPublicKey: String, aesKey: ByteArray?): String {
    var result: String? = null
    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    val keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(rsaPublicKey.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")))
    val spec = X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes)
    val fileGeneratedPublicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec)
    val key = fileGeneratedPublicKey as RSAPublicKey
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
    val byteEncryptedData = cipher.doFinal(aesKey)
    return String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteEncryptedData))
}
```

But it only works over Oreo(Android OS veresion, API 26). But I need to make it work under API 26. At most API 24. Is there any alternative way to implement it?

Comment: Also `return String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteEncryptedData), charset("UTF-8"))` as ASCII will not work on platforms with default UTF-16 or EBCDIC.

Comment: Well, I am looking for java code. Not from android library. @DalijaPrasnikar

Comment: @JoopEggen I don't get it. You mean "UTF-8" is useless here?

Comment: No, for encode Base64, which delivers ASCII bytes, you still need for conversion to String specify an encoding, as the default could not be a superset of ASCII. `new String(byte[], Charset)` to explicitly define the charset of the bytes. However you can skip the step in java with `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString`

Comment: You have Android tag in the question. You ask about older Android API. I don't understand what is the problem. If you want to implement algorithm yourself, then this is entirely different question. In that case you should start doing that, there is plenty information on how Base64 works and if you get stuck on implementation, then you can ask about specific issue.